# Function on event click in jquery runs on pageload

Tags: jquery

How come function is run on pageload? I see 4 alerts, as if on page load each button is clicked once.

```
//Leaderboard switch alltime-week
$("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_all_time_btn"));
$("#leader_month_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_month_btn"));
$("#leader_week_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_week_btn"));
$("#leader_day_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_day_btn"));


//This is for above
function leadboard_switch_period(btn_id) {
    $("#leaderboard_nav a").removeClass("active_lb_btn");
    alert("yes");
    return false;
}
```

Also since I'm opening a topic :) 
`$("#leader_month_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_month_btn"));`

how can I rewrite this, so that I don't have to write button id twice? this.id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've missed the function bit havn't you

```
$("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", function() {
  leadboard_switch_period($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `leadboard_switch_period` function at the time you bind it. That means the *return value* of it is passed to `.on()`, when actually you need to pass a reference to a function.

You could get your `leadboard_switch_period` function to return a function that will be used as the event handler:

```
function leadboard_switch_period(btn_id) {
    return function () {
        $("#leaderboard_nav a").removeClass("active_lb_btn");
        alert("yes");
        return false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_all_time_btn"))` calls this function instantly. You should replace it with

```
$("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", function(){
    //inside this function $("#leader_all_time_btn") is this
    leadboard_switch_period(this)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind the fact the question asked how it could be done without re-writing the statement twice (which no other answer has done...), you can do this in a single jQuery selector, assigned to one function to make your code cleaner.

```
$("#leader_all_time_btn, #leader_month_btn, #leader_week_btn, #leader_day_btn").on("click", function() {
    alert("#" + this.id); // Get the ID of the button that was clicked and add a hashtag, or $(this) for the whole element.
    $("#leaderboard_nav a").removeClass("active_lb_btn");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery .on() method expects a selector and a callback (in this case), you are actually passing the result of a function execution, this is why it is called 4 times at start, what you want is something like:

```
$("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period);

function leadboard_switch_period(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // If instead of a button you use a link, but dont want the default behavior
  var btn_id = this.id; // this refers to the clicked button
}
```

Note that by passing "leadboard_switch_period" onto the .on method you are passing the callback to that function, while doing "leadboard_switch_period(bla)" you are actually calling the function and passing its result to the .on method.

When you click the element jQuery will call your function with the event as the first parameter and the clicked element as the context object (this).

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

      //Leaderboard switch alltime-week
      $("#leader_all_time_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_all_time_btn"));  
      $("#leader_month_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_month_btn"));
      $("#leader_week_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_week_btn"));
      $("#leader_day_btn").on("click", leadboard_switch_period("#leader_day_btn"));


    });

    //This function need to be invoked on function call..
    //You can even call from jquery event....
     function leadboard_switch_period(btn_id) {
     $("#leaderboard_nav a").removeClass("active_lb_btn");
     alert("yes");
     return false;
     }
```